# Kavanah while washing hands

Tags: halacha, number, netilat-yadayim-washing, kavana-concentration

When washing the hands, either before bread, or in the morning, must you have the correct kavanah (intent)?

For example, if i pick up the cup in the morning thinking i'll do 2-2 (like washing for bread), but then remember that i have to do 1-1×3 (like regular washing in the morning) after the first one, does it count?

Comment: מצוות צריכות כוונה?

Comment: first off what washing are you referring to the tumah washing or before davening washing with a bracha, whatever the case is its a metzyius ,you washed and fulfilled the washing that needs to be done,however washing off tumah needs seirugin and washing for bread does not work ,you would have to do it again.